# How to remove a standard property from a PropertyGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I am creating a graphing interface and would like to give the user the option to edit the graphs look, i.e. Series color, BackColor, Data point size, etc... The chart is being created using

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
```

To allow the user to edit those options I've placed a PropertyGrid in the form. However there are some properties I do not want the user to have access to. I would like to be able to set up a chart in my form then create a propertygrid that is connected to that chart but have certain properties removed from the grid. 
What I have so far tried is ...

```
public partial class Form1: Form 
{
    PropertyGrid propG1 = new PropertyGrid();
    this.Controls.Add(propG1);

    //... There is code here where my chart(chart1) is being populated with data 
    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// The button is just to test 
    MyChart myC = new MyChart(); 
    propG1.SelectedObject = myC; 
}
```

So based on the recomendations I've received so far I've created a class called MyChart which contains the properties that I don't want to be displayed on my chart.

```
using System.ComponentModel
//...

public class MyChart : Chart 
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public new System.Drawing.Color Property
    {
        get{return BackColor;}  // BackColor is just an example not necessarily a property I'd like to remove
        set{base.BackColor = value;}
    }
```

I haven't been able to remove the properties from my grid nor have I been able to connect myC with my chart1 so when a property is changed in the grid chart1 is affected. Thanks for the continuing help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying the PropertyGrid component and its behavior you can modify the objects that you display with attributes. Something like this:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public object SomeProperty
{
}
```

Don't forget to add:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

And to override inherited properties and hide them from the propertyGrid you could do something like:

```
public class Chart : BaseChart
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public new string BaseString // notice the new keyword!
    {
        get { return base.BaseString; } // notice the base keyword!
        set { base.BaseString = value; }
    }

    // etc.
}

public class BaseChart
{
    public string BaseString { get; set; }
}
```

Setting the Browsable attribute to false will keep SomeProperty from showing up in the PropertyGrid.

So, in a hypothetical chart class like the one below, you will see the chart instance, the SomeProperty1 property but not SomeProperty2.

```
public class Chart
{
    public object Property1 { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public object Property2 { get; set; }

    // etc.
}
```

See [Getting the most out of your property grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) for more information. And here is a very, very good deep-dive into [customizing the PropertyGrid control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13630/Add-Custom-Properties-to-a-PropertyGrid) that will blow your mind. ;-)

And, even more fun with attributes and the PropertyGrid:

```
[DefaultPropertyAttribute("Property1")]
public class Chart
{
    [CategoryAttribute("My Properties"),
     DescriptionAttribute("My demo property int"),
     DefaultValueAttribute(10)]
    public int Property1 { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public object Property2 { get; set; }

    [CategoryAttribute("My Properties"),
     DescriptionAttribute("My demo property string"),
     DefaultValueAttribute("Hello World!")]
    public string Property3 { get; set; }

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do a button. Simply by reacting to a change of selection in your UI you should have the instance of the object you need to display properties for. In that handler also asign the SelectedObject property of the PropertyGrid. But if you only have one chart then there is no selection and you simply assign the property when you instantiate your chart object.

Comment: Is there a way to do that with standard properties. For example BackColor for a chart or the text property for a button?

Comment: Yes, very much so. The PropertyGrid can even handle the .NET Color type as is. No special coding necessary. Those properties just need to be public.

Comment: One last question. I am having trouble seeing how to connect the standard properties of a chart and then setting some of those to be non-visible. Would it be something like `Class Chart: myChart`. I am going to be playing around with this and hopefully I'll eventually figure it out, but who doesn't love a hint once in a while.

Comment: Yes, to set extra attributes on properties that you inherit from another class you will either have to wrap the properties or override them or `new` them. It all depends on how the parent class defines its properties.

Comment: @user2023068 : OK. I think I see now what you want to do. Check out the latest edit on the answer where I create a Chart class and inherit from BaseChart and wrap its property with the new keyword and then use the base keyword to still allow the underlying value to be manipulated.

Comment: I think I now understand what you're saying but just for clarification. You're suggesting I create a MyCclas class(which would be equivalent to your Chart class) and create an actual chart(from system...charting) so it would look something like this `using System...Charting public class MyChart:Chart [Browsable(false)] public string Property1  get { return base.Property1; }set { base.Property1= value; }//Property1 Ex)BackColor which would be inherited from a chart I have in the form` to implement it in the form it would be something like `Chart c1=new Chart(); MyCclas mC=new MyClas();Mc=c1;`

Comment: You're close. You do not need to instantiate two classes though. Since, in your example, MyCclas inherits from Chart then MyCclas automatically has everything that Chart has. All you need is: `MyCclas mC=new MyClas();`

Comment: I'm having one last problem of binding my property grid with my chart so that when I change something in the grid my chart will change with it.

Comment: You will have to post some code. I suggest opening another question.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It really gave me the tools to better understand the property grid. Also I have opened up another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096971/how-to-connect-a-custom-propertygrid-with-a-standard-control-in-c that deals with connecting custom property grids and standard controls