# How to connect a custom propertyGrid with a standard control in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I am creating a graphing program and I would like to allow the user to be able to change the look of the graph they create. Providing them with the opportunity to change the series color, data point size, ect. I am allowing them to do this through the use of a propertyGrid. Through the help of the wonderful people who use stack overflow I was able to import all the properties of a chart into my property grid, however; Now I can't figure out how to connect my chart to the propertyGrid, so when I change something in the grid the chart changes.

So far I have

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        magRadioBox.Checked = true;
        PropertyGrid propertyGrid1 = new PropertyGrid();
        propertyGrid1.CommandsVisibleIfAvailable = true;
        propertyGrid1.Text = "Graph and Plotting Options";
        propertyGrid1.PropertyValueChanged += propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged;

        this.Controls.Add(propertyGrid1);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "MY Plot Program";
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = chart1; 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //some code that is populating my chart(chart1) with data 
        //....chart1 being filled with data 
    }

    private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s , PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Getting the MyChart instance from propertyGrid 
        MyChart myChart = (MyChart)(((PropertyGrid)s.SelectedObject);
        //Calling the method that will refresh my chart1 
        myChart.Invalidate(); 
    }
```

The above code is for my Form. The my "MyChart" class code is

```
namespace FFT_Plotter
{ 
    [DefaultPropertyAttribute("Text")]
    public class MyChart : Chart 
    {
        public event EventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler eh = propertyChanged;
            if(eh !=null)
            {
                eh(sender, e);
            }

            [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
            public new System.Drawing.Color BackColor
            {
                get { return BackColor; }//Here back color is just an example of a property, not necessarily one that I would make non-Browsable
                set 
                { 
                    base.BackColor = value; 
                    OnPropertyChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The class above gets me so far as having a property grid that has all the properties of a chart and allows me to hide those properties as I see fit. However now I am stuck in understanding how to connect my chart1 to the grid I've created. If anyone has any advice on how to do that, it would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = myChartInstance;`, then you have to add `PropertyValueChanged` event listener that will be triggered each time a user changes `myChartInstance` property via `PropertyGrid`. So, assuming that you want to redraw the chart each time the change has been done, the code should look like this:

```
        private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object sender, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           // Redraw the chart.
           chart1.Invalidate();
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            magRadioBox.Checked = true;
            PropertyGrid propertyGrid1 = new PropertyGrid();
            propertyGrid1.CommandsVisibleIfAvailable = true;
            propertyGrid1.Text = "Graph and Plotting Options";

            // Create your chart.
            chart1 = new MyChart();

            // Attach your chart to Property Grid.
            propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = (MyChart) chart1;
            propertyGrid1.PropertyValueChanged += propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged;

            this.Controls.Add(propertyGrid1);
        }
```

Comment: I think the OP means going the other way. I.E. How to make the chart component reflect a change that was made to a property in the ProeprtyGrid. E.G. The user changes the back color in the PropertyGrid -> How to get the chart its back color in response?

Comment: I don't see how this will work (Not that it doesn't work). When you say "pass the same instance of the chart to both the property grid and your control." Do you mean something like `public Form1()... MyChart myChartInstance = new MyChart(); chart1 = myChartInstance; propertyGrid.SelectedObject = myChartInstance; ...` If not then I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: @user2023068 Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Also, I updated the answer, so it shows you the way you could get your control notified on myChartInstance property change.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I'm now using but I am still really confused on how to "hook up" my controller. I think you mean `private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e){ //somehow using myC.PropertyChanged and somehow chart1.Invalidate  and somehow chart1.Refresh() }
`

Comment: @user2023068 That's one way of how it could be done. Is your chart drawing algorithm in the same class as `MyChart`?

Comment: Well, MyChart is getting much of it's structure from Chart, and chart has it's own drawing methods, so I would say yes, although, not explicitly.

Comment: @user2023068 Ok, so it makes things easier. I've just updated my answer.

Comment: @Dzienny, Thank you so much for your help so far. Yet, I am still very lost. I've updated my question code fragments to reflect what I think you are implying but so far I haven't been able to get any of it to work. From what you've written above I interpret it as - 1) I'm setting up the propertyGrid1 to have a new event handler i.e. the += part 2) myChartInstance == chart1 (for me) 3) the propertygrid is calling chart1 and converting it to a myChart and then I'm updating my chart with invalidate.

Comment: @Dzienny, Thank you for your help so far, the above comment is no longer relvant. I have been working this morning and have gotten it to do some wierd stuff. When I change a property in the grid the `private void propertyGrid_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e){MyChart myChart = (MyChart)(((PropertyGrid)s).SelectedObject); myChart.Invalidate(); } Portion of the code is giving me an error of invalid cast exception: Unable to cast...System...Chart to type FFT_Plotter.MyChart but if I continue running the code it will change that property.

Comment: @user2023068 You can just replace the content `propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged` to just `chart1.Invalidate();`. This way you will access the chart control directly, and you don't have to worry about casting.

Comment: @Dzienny I don't understand what you mean. Are you saying `private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s, ...){chart1.Invalidate()}` is all I have to do? Or are you saying I should create something like `private void chart1_Invalidate(object s, EventArgs e){ MyChart myC = new MyChart(); chart1 = myC; }`

Comment: @user2023068 The first one. And remember, _do not_ create a new instance of `MyChart` unless you are going to pass it to `propertyGrid1.SelectedObject` just after. Otherwise the `propertyGrid1` will get detached from your chart.

Comment: @Dzienny, I believe this puts me back to my original problem. I am now just using the chart1's property grid instead of the one I've created. Right now my code never declares a MyChart class.

Comment: @user2023068 If you created a new `MyChart` object just inform `PropertyGrid` about it, by setting its `SelectedObject` to new instance. It should look like this: `propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = newInstanceOfMyChart;`

Comment: @Dzienny I'm going to real talk right now. I am utterly confounded. I don't see where I should implement the `MyChart` class and how to connect that to `chart1`. What I've tried so far is `private void Form1_Load(...){propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = chart1 ; }` `private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(...){MyChart myChart = new MyChart(); chart1 = myChart; chart1.Invalidate(); ` I've also tried your previous suggestion of just having `chart1.Invalidate()` but none of these things seem to work.

Comment: @user2023068 What do you mean by this doesn't seem to work? Are you gettin any error, etc.?

Comment: @Dzienny. I mean that the property Grid is not connected to my chart. When I change a property in the grid the chart doesn't change. If I use my code above I get a cast error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25238/discussion-between-dzienny-and-user2023068)

Comment: @user2023068 I updated the code. I added `new MyChart()` line to the code. The sequence is important. And, if you have anywhere in the `Form1` code `new MyChart()` you have to remove it as it will break it! Instead of `MyChart myChart = new MyChart()` use `MyChart myChart = (MyChart) chart1`.

Answer (score 0):

Through the help of the great community on StackOverflow this was the answer I was able to piece together, (standing on the shoulders of giants)

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                magRadioBox.Checked = true;
                PropertyGrid propertyGrid1 = new PropertyGrid();
                propertyGrid1.CommandsVisibleIfAvailable = true;
                propertyGrid1.Text = "Graph and Plotting Options";
                propertyGrid1.PropertyValueChanged += propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged;

                this.Controls.Add(propertyGrid1);
            } private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { this.Text = "MY Plot Program"; propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = chart1;  }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  {//some code that is populating my chart(chart1) with data   .... //chart1 being filled with data   }

        private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s , PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e) { 
myChart.Invalidate();  
}
```

This is the code for the `MyChart` class

```
namespace FFT_Plotter
{ 
    [DefaultPropertyAttribute("Text")]// This is where the initial position of the grid is set 
    public class MyChart : Chart 
    {
        public event EventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
EventHandler eh = propertyChanged;
if(eh !=null)
{
eh(sender, e);
}
        [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        public new System.Drawing.Color BackColor
        {
            get { return BackColor; }//Here back color is just an example of a property, not necessarily one that I would make non-Browsable
            set { 
base.BackColor = value; 
OnPropertyChanged(this,EventArgs.Empty);
}
        }
    }
}
```

And this declares `chart1` to be a `MyChart` rather than `System.Windows...Chart`, in the Form1.Designer.CS

```
...this.chart1  = new FFT_Ploter.MyChart(); ... private FFT_Plotter.MyChart chart1;
```